# AB-BA so that you get another matrix

Tags: matrices

I want to find out what the matrices are (a) and (b) so that $ab-ba = $

$$
\begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end {pmatrix} $$

This is the outcome of $ab-ba$ is. Ive been struggling with this for the past hour or so. All matrices have to be $4\times,4$

Comment: ignore the 1 in the title.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Do you mean that $AB - BA = I$, the identity matrix?

Comment: He means $AB-BA=$ that matrix guys.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes I need it to equal that matrix.

Comment: Sorry. it was a mistake with how I formatted the question when I was writing it.

Comment: @Buriki It seems to me that $A$ and $B$ which satisfy this condition cannot be uniquely determined, since we have only 16 conditions while we have 32 unknown variables. Do you want just one example of $(A,B)$, or more or less generalized form?

Comment: One example that includes Matrix A and Matrix B, I can use a calculator to do the rest.

Comment: Just one suggestion: A straightforward (albeit laborious, analytically at least) way to attack this problem can be to fix the matrix $A$ and to construct a system of equation for elements of $B$. We should be aware of the fact that the system does not have a solution if we choose $A$ inappropriately (trivial example is $A=I$).

Comment: This may work: Given: $AB-BA=X$, assume that $A^{-1}=X$. Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ to get $B-A^{-1}BA=I$. We know $A^{-1}$ and We Know $A$, so B can be found with some work.

Comment: @NoChance I'm afraid this may not work. There is a case where $B-A^{-1}BA=I$ does not have a solution. One trivial example is $X=I$, although I'm not sure the problem here falls into this case.

Comment: @KatieImach, $X$ is already given and it is not equal to $I$.

Comment: @NoChance I'm aware of that, and thus I'm not sure your method works or not here. My point is that it is not guaranteed that the method works. Note also that $X$ in this problem is rather similar to $I$.

Answer (score 2):

I like $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
    B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \text{.} $$

Comment: Man I was over thinking this. Im running it through a calculator and I see what it is doing thanks.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @user230452 : Just poked at it.  Started with the conditions ("$a_{11} \cdot b_\text{blah} - \dots = 1, \dots$") on the diagonal and partially solved, then added the "${}=0$" conditions for the off-diagonal a pair at a time (picking pairs that simplified the working expressions).  I tried a few other less nuts-and-bolts approaches without much progress.  My opinion is there might still be a shortcut using the symmetric-antisymmetric decomposition, but such a shortcut eluded me.